# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer Triggering Multiple Times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following code in a viewDidLoad on a UIViewController:

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *edgeRecognizer = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRightEdgeSwipe:)];
edgeRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:edgeRecognizer];
```

and the purposes is to trigger a view to slide in when a right edge gesture is detected.

```
-(void)handleRightEdgeSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
NSLog(@"Showing Side Bar");
[self presentPanelViewController:_lightPanelViewController withDirection:MCPanelAnimationDirectionRight];
}
```

But I am seeing that the "handleRightEdgeSwipe" function is triggered multiple times - sometimes 5 times which makes the side bar view that should smoothly animate slide in to flash multiple times.

(NOTE: I tried triggering the view to appear from a UIButton and it works fine).

Why is the right edge gesture triggered multiple times and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you want it to move in, not drag with your finger, you should use a UISwipeGestureRecognizer instead. It recognizes a single event rather than a continuous motion.

Comment: @rdelmar I only want to trigger on an edge swipe.  How can I use UISwipeGestureRecognizer on right edge?

Comment: In the action method, you need to look at the value of locationInView:, and only trigger the action if the x value of that location is within the area you want.

Answer (score 22):

As noted, the UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer invokes your action multiple times as the state of the GestureRecognizer changes.  See the documentation for the **state** property of the **UIGestureRecognizer** class.  So, in your case I believe the answer you're looking for is to check if the state is "ended".  Thus:

```
-(void)handleRightEdgeSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"Showing Side Bar");
        [self presentPanelViewController:_lightPanelViewController withDirection:MCPanelAnimationDirectionRight];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This gesture is not a single-shot event but continuous.

`handleRightEdgeSwipe:` is called once whenever `sender.state` changes or the touch moved around. You have to move the `UIButton` depending on the gesture's `state` and `locationInView:`.

Comment: do you have an example for your answer?  I only want to trigger on the right edge.